# Another word for "effective", but not indicating a satisfactory solution

Tags: single-word-requests

Here is the sentence:

> There are ways around requiring Proxy ARP on a NAT device, but that involves using a Static Route on the Router to manually instruct it to send packets which must be translated to the Firewall’s interface. While **effective**, this solution does not scale.

Here is a similar sentence that won't require understanding the technical jargon:

> There are ways to get around requiring toilet paper, but that would involve getting your hands dirty. While **effective**, this solution does not scale.

The idea is the "other solution" works, is feasible and would technically accomplish the goal. BUT, is not ideal or even suggested as a "good solution" to the problem.

The word "effective" works, but I feel it conveys too much positive sentiment for what I am trying to accomplish.

"Feasible" is also a potential candidate, but leaves to vague about the solution working at all (aka, it's possible, doesn't mean 100% certain to work). The solution in both of the sentences above *absolutely* work, but are *absolutely* not the most ideal way of doing things, and therefore not *effective* solutions to the problem.

Single word preferred, but willing to do multi-word. Would rather *avoid* a colloquialism.

Comment: Maybe "successful", "efficacious", or "valid"?

Comment: @Hank ooh, I like *valid*. Let me see what else comes in, but that could work. Thanks Hank!

Comment: Valid has more to do with logic or law, like a valid point or valid contract. "Sufficient" or "viable" could work

Comment: A typical reply to that sort of "solution" is "that is a possibility" .  That acknowledges the validity of something put forward but implies you're not quite comfortable that there isn't a better solution that might come up with more consideration.

Comment: @the_darkside Those are some definitions and usages of the word "valid" but not all.

Comment: if you want to suggest that it would work but that you believe that it is not a very good solution at all, you could call it a "last resort" .

Comment: The fact that the solution does not scale suggests to me that the solution is fine in a restricted situation (for example a single router as part of a small network) but does not translate to a more complex environment with more nodes. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Tom22 The suggestion will work (definitively), it just doesn't work as a final solution. If I were thinking of ways to avoid stocking my public restroom with Toiler paper, sure people could use their hands to clean up after themselves, and while *viable*, the solution is not ideal.

Comment: @Eddie The bathroom example is pretty extreme, so I guess you're getting at something that "really isn't even in consideration despite technically being an option" ? "an unacceptable alternative"?

Comment: @Tom22 Maybe instead of "really isn't even in consideration despite technically being an option", only rarely being an option, but you're going out of your way to find a less optimal solution to a problem that is already solved itself if you just leave it be.  If that makes sense.

Comment: @Eddie my regrets.  I was trying to help brainstorm, and I didn't grasp that you had found an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Tom22 No worries! You did help me frame the context better. I hadn't actually picked an answer yet, although at this point I think it will be **viable**, as suggested by the_darkside

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***valid*** will work in this instance.

> #### Valid
>
> (adjective) Appropriate to the end in view; producing the desired result.

([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valid))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try [sufficient](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sufficient?s=t)?

> adjective
>
> 1. adequate for the purpose; enough: sufficient proof; sufficient protection.

So you are saying the solution will work, but it is not exceptional.

Answer (score 1):

You could also say, "While this is **one means to the desired end**, this solution does not scale."

Answer (score 0):

**possibility** or "*that is a possibility*"

[cambridge dictionary: possibility](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/possibility)

> possibility
>
> noun UK ​ /ˌpɒs.əˈbɪl.ə.ti/ US ​ /ˌpɑː.səˈbɪl.ə.t̬i/
>   ​
>
> B1 [ C or U ] a chance that something may happen or be true:
>
> It's not likely to happen but I wouldn't rule out the possibility.
>   The forecast said that there's a possibility of snow tonight.
>   [ + (that) ] There's a distinct possibility (that) I'll be asked to give a speech.
>   Is there any possibility (that) you could pick me up from the station?
>   Opposite
>   ​
>
> B2 [ C ] **something that you can choose to do in a particular situation:**
>
> We could take on extra staff - that's one possibility.
>
> "Have you decided what to do?" "No, I'm still considering the various possibilities."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***rudimentary*** solution works here.

ODO:

> **[rudimentary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rudimentary)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** Relating to an immature, undeveloped, or basic form
>
> ‘They occur frequently in the mines, which often lack even rudimentary
>   safety equipment such as ventilators to disperse the gas.’